# Can't activate Google App Engine's TaskQueue API

Tags: api, google-app-engine, queue, task, task-queue

I can't find where to activate the Google App Engine Task Queue API within the Google Developers Console - it is simply not in the list.

I've followed the instructions found here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/rest/about_auth

Comment: Me neither! I don't think its enabled by default because I don't see the taskqueue API on the "Enabled APIS" list. Besides, I keep getting the:
"You are not allowed to make this api call" whenever I try to access it form my GCE instance (I've set the scopes and service account). By the way, I see that the list named "Google APIs", only shows popular APIs and not all of them.